# Checking if a substring exists in a counter dictionary of strings

Tags: python

Suppose I have a `collections.Counter` object like this

```
c = Counter({('paragraphs', 'are', 'the'): 1,
         ('are', 'the', 'building'): 1,
         ('the', 'building', 'blocks'): 1,
         ('building', 'blocks', 'of'): 1,
         ('blocks', 'of', 'papers'): 1,
         ('many', 'students', 'define'): 1,
         ('students', 'define', 'paragraphs'): 1,
         ('define', 'paragraphs', 'in'): 1,
         ('paragraphs', 'in', 'terms'): 1,
         ('in', 'terms', 'of'): 1})
```

Now suppose I have a list

```
l = ['many', 'students']
```

I want to check if `l` is a subset of any of `c`'s items. Since `c` has `('many', 'students', 'define')` then by my definition `l` is a subset of `c`.

Comment: What have you done to even *attempt* to solve this problem?

Comment: `if any(all(word in key for word in l) for key in c) :` should work

Comment: "Since c has ('many', 'students', 'define') then by my definition l is contained in c." By _definition_ it is not contained in `c`. "contained in" has a very specific meaning in Python which means that there is an exact matching key. And your `l` is a list, which is not hashable and can't be used as a key in the first place

Comment: @BradSolomon What would be the correct terminology then? I am more using a mathematical definition.

Comment: The term in set theory would be a [_subset_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) as shown by @azro

Comment: @BradSolomon Thanks I adjusted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set.issubset` operation

```
l = {'many', 'students'}
for k, v in c.items():
    if l.issubset(k):
        print(k, v)
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without iterating through c? or perhaps a one-liner?

Comment: @justanewb what does the code should do with it :collect in a list or print it ? You need to iterate, then you can just reorder in a list comprehension `[(k,v) for k, v in c.items() if l.issubset(k)]`